# Vuejs renders redundant whitespaces in HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am facing an issue with rendering strings using Vue.
Currently if HTML tag is opened and closed on different lines e.g.

```
<span class="description">
    {{ text }}
</span>
```

it gets rendered as following

```
<span class="description">
            text
          </span>
```

Which leads to `document.querySelector('.description').textContent`
returning string that contains redundant white spaces. E.g.

```
"
          Text
        "
```

I found out that if you open and close HTML tag that contains a string on the same line, the issue is gone. E.g.

```
<span class="description">{{ text }}</span>
```

Question: Can I somehow enforce Vue to render text without additional spaces **without** formatting all actual HTML, meaning having tags opened and closed on different lines? (I am not alone working on this project)
Alternatively, can I somehow enforce formatting as shown in the last example? We are currently using ESLint and Prittier, but after a thorough search I couldn't find anything fitting my  use case.

Thank you!

More context:
Why do I care about those spaces? In our selenium tests I sometimes find elements by text and having these spaces makes it impossible. Furthermore, I understand that I might use css-selectors, but some elements just don't have unique selectors, so I get them by text.

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "element-theme": "^2.0.1",
    "element-theme-chalk": "^2.4.11",
    "element-ui": "^2.13.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "memoizee": "^0.4.14",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.10.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.16.3",
    "v-calendar": "^1.0.0-beta.23",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-flag-icon": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.8.0",
    "vue-json-pretty": "^1.6.3",
    "vue-tour": "^1.3.0",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.17.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "bee-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "google-maps-api-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "html-inject-script": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.26",
    "nightwatch": "^1.0.11",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "raven-js": "^3.22.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^3.6.2",
    "svgo": "^1.0.4",
    "svgo-loader": "^2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "v-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

.prettierrc

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "htmlWhiteSpaceSensitivity": "ignore"
}
```

.eslintrc.js

```
// https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint",
    sourceType: "module"
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    jquery: true
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:vue/recommended",
    "prettier/vue",
    "standard",
  ],
  plugins: ["vue"],
  rules: {
    "space-before-function-paren": "off",

    "vue/require-default-prop": "off",
    "vue/require-prop-types": "off",
    "vue/attributes-order": "off",
    "vue/order-in-components": "off",
    "vue/no-v-html": "off",
    "vue/require-v-for-key": "off",
    "vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for": "off",
    "vue/return-in-computed-property": "off",
    "vue/require-valid-default-prop": "off",
    "vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties": "off",
    "vue/no-duplicate-attributes": "off",
    "vue/no-async-in-computed-properties": "off",
    "vue/mustache-interpolation-spacing": "error",
  }
};
```

Comment: why do you need `document.querySelector`?

Comment: And why do you need `.textContent`. If you need the full inner markup concatinate it using vue so you have a tracked reference.

Comment: I added more context in the question. I need .textContent because in my Selenium tests I get some elements by text. And if those elements' textContent contains redundant spaces, I cannot find that element by text. 
For example, if I want to get some values from table on the page, I wouldn't have unique selectors for each row. That's why I would rather search an element by text to confirm that expected entry is shown in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if youre actual case is that simple but for tags, that don't contain extra markup I would always use `v-text`, where possible:

```html
<span class="description" v-text="text" />
```

Notice the self-closing `<span />` which isn't required but indicates even more this element has no internal markup.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not that easy. I could edit all of the existing tags as per last example, but my issue is not to fix it temporally but prevent it from happening in the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove empty spaces?

```js
let str = '   example ';

console.log(str.trim(), str);
```

```js
let desc = document.getElementsByClassName('description')[0];

console.log(desc.textContent, desc.textContent.trim());
```

```html
<span class="description">
            text
          </span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, trim() doesn't really solve it for me. I added some more context to the post, but long story short, I am writing selenium tests and getting some elements by text.